# THREE js models are getting black in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, three.js

[image]I am loading 10 models at a time as shown in image. I am using different camera n scene everything different for each model. In IE I am getting problem of crashing or something else. Can I get help from anyone, what could be exactly a problem.
I have WebGLRenderer 77 version and IE 11.[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console? Any code that we can see?

Comment: Also, if possible, please upgrade the latest version. It makes it easier for us to help debug if we don't have to go download an old version.

Comment: Hello, I have added one more pic where I am getting those warnings. Is it issue of memory management?

Comment: Problem I am facing in only IE.